# flipbook-images in even pages

Tags: positioning

I have made a flip book but I would like to ask a couple of questions. First, I want I would like to place the images only in even pages of the book. Also, I would like to place the images in the upper right corner of every page, but I cannot find a way to do it. I have posted the code and two pages from the book.
Any advice is appreciated.

```
\documentclass[a5paper,pagesize,12pt,bibtotoc,pointlessnumbers,
normalheadings,twoside=false,DIV=9]{scrbook}

\usepackage{helvet}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}

\KOMAoptions{DIV=last}

\usepackage{trajan}

\usepackage[english,greek]{babel}
\usepackage{ucs}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{kerkis}

\usepackage{sectsty}
\chapterfont{\centering}

\usepackage[sc]{mathpazo}
\linespread{1.05} 

\usepackage{listings} % for comments

\usepackage{verse}
\renewcommand{\poemtoc}{subsection}

\usepackage{tikz} 
\usepackage{everypage}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\usepackage{xspace}
\usepackage{url}

\def\PageTopMargin{-12cm}

\def\PageLeftMargin{0.5cm}

\newcounter{frame number}

\newcommand\animatexy[3]{%
 \gdef\image_1.png{#3\theframenumber}%
 \AddEverypageHook{{\hspace*{\dimexpr-\PageLeftMargin-\hoffset+#1\relax}%
  \raisebox{\dimexpr-\PageTopMargin+\voffset-#2\relax}{%
  \includegraphics[scale=0.1]{\image_1.png}}}}%
}

\AddEverypageHook{\stepcounter{framenumber}%
  \ifnum\theframenumber>55\setcounter{framenumber}{55}\fi}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\newcommand{\q}[1]{>>\textit{#1}<<}

\title{ΜΙΑ ΜΟΝΑΔΙΚΗ ΙΣΤΙΟΠΛΟΪΚΗ ΕΜΠΕΙΡΙΑ}   
\author{ΗΛΕΚΤΡΥΩΝ ΑΓΝΩΣΤΙΔΗΣ} 
\date{\today} 


\begin{document}
\animatexy{10.5cm}{12.cm}{image_}
\pagestyle{plain}

\begin{titlepage}
            \centering{
                    {\fontsize{10}{18}\selectfont 
                    ΗΛΕΚΤΡΥΩΝ ΑΓΝΩΣΤΙΔΗΣ}
            }\\

            \vspace{10mm}
            \centering{\Large{ΜΙΑ ΜΟΝΑΔΙΚΗ ΙΣΤΙΟΠΛΟΪΚΗ ΕΜΠΕΙΡΙΑ}}\\
            \vspace{\fill}
            \centering \large{ΑΘΗΝΑΙ 2014}
\end{titlepage}

\newpage{}
\thispagestyle {empty}

\vspace*{2cm}

\begin{center}
    \Large{\parbox{10cm}{
            \begin{raggedright}
            {\Large 
                    \textit{Επαίνετος πάντων έφη τούς ψεύστας τών       αμαρτημάτων καί τών αδικημάτων αιτίους είναι.}
            }

            \vspace{.5cm}\hfill{Πλούταρχος}
            \end{raggedright}
    }
}
\end{center}

\newpage

\tableofcontents!
```

[image: first_page]
[image: Second_page]

Comment: i think you mean "odd" (right-hand) pages, not "even".  if you were setting the images on the left-hand pages, they wouldn't be very effective.

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean. I also want the figures to appear only on pages 2, 4, 6, 8, etc...